# Date of swearing in US congressmen

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives

What is the date for the swearing in ceremony of newly elected U.S. representatives and senators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The New Congressional members, and returning congressional members, were sworn in on the 3 of January, 2017.

Google search terms: New congress sworn in date

Answer (score -1):

Congressional terms begin on January 3rd.  The date is fixed by the first section of the 20th amendment:

> The terms of the President and Vice President shall end at noon on the 20th day of January, and the terms of Senators and Representatives at noon on the 3d day of January, of the years in which such terms would have ended if this article had not been ratified; and the terms of their successors shall then begin.

Section 2 goes on to say:

> The Congress shall assemble at least once in every year, and such meeting shall begin at noon on the 3d day of January, unless they shall by law appoint a different day.

The 20th amendment was ratified in January 1933.  Before then, the president's term of office and those of the congress began on the same day: March 4th.

For more information, see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twentieth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution.